# How do I calculate the diode parameters for reverse polarity protection?

Tags: diodes, reverse-polarity

I understand that a diode allows current to flow in one direction only, and that inserting a diode in series with a power source will protect the circuit from a reverse polarity battery.

How do I calculate what capacity diode is appropriate? I want to minimize the voltage drop as the battery is a one cell lithium unit with maximum 4.2V.  The device (a camera) seems to shut itself off when the battery hits 3.8V.

[image]

Comment: First thing you need to know is the current consumed by the device. But you seem to be in trouble as even the "low-vf" diodes are having Vf around 0.4V (https://www.st.com/en/diodes-and-rectifiers/power-schottky-low-vf.html?querycriteria=productId=SS1617).

Comment: You might want to consider using a low Vth P-channel FET as reverse polarity protection device instead of a diode.  Another option would be using a diode across the input with a fuse, resettable or other.

Comment: Is this from motor kickback turning off or just battery reversed?

Comment: What kind of protection do you mean, against what? Against an operator mistake to connect it in reverse, or else?

Comment: if you care more about the camera than the power source, you can put a a several amp diode across the red and black wire; no drop in normal operation, 99%+ drop in reverse. fuse in front would blow in that condition, if you don't like shorting batteries for long periods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For such a low allowable drop, you need a *zero voltage drop diode*. It can be done with a P-Channel enhancement mode MOSFET. E.g. a IRFD9120 is sufficient for up to 1A drain current.

(Use a multimeter and check how much current your camera draws. Check it with display on and zoom moving.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGEu3S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any diode or transistor for reverse polarity protection. The RC toy hobby industry offers a dozen of [**polarity-protected connectors**](http://eastbay-rc.blogspot.com/2010/12/connector-chart.html), rated from 1 A to 100 A. You just can't plug them in reverse, mechanically. This was the solution for RC toy industry, where underage operators may be very unreliable and irresponsible.

[image]

Comment: This is good information.  As you can see in my photo, I'm "cheating" on my battery usage by tapping into a single cell of a 3 cell RC battery, currently using just two non-polarized pins.  I can use your idea by having three different cables, each wired to appropriately tap off a different cell (using the battery's balance connector).